# Missing first column when converting value_count series to data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and programming in general. I have some experience with R and finding pandas a little difficult.

I am trying to conduct a frequency count and then return this as a DataFrame object.

`df = pd.read_csv('gender_data.csv')`

`x = df['Gender'].value_counts()`

This  returns the following series object:

```
       Gender
Male    200
Female  100
```

I want to convert this into a DataFrame object so I can plot and specify the axes information. This is where I am having a problem because .to_frame() cuts off the category label from the series.

```
x.to_frame()
```

returns

```
Gender
200
100
```

Is there a way to convert the series into a DataFrame and keep the category column? In R I think I could achieve this by using as.data.frame(x)

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce this. What version of pandas are you on?

Comment: Pandas version: 0.19.2, I'm using the Rodeo IDE which is a bit like RStudio but for Python if that makes a difference?

Comment: What exactly would you like the final plot to look like? It seems like the final plot should be a frequency histogram with two bins, male and female? The reason I ask is because I'm wondering why you need to convert the series to a data frame in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"gender": ["male", "female", "male", "male", "female"]})
df = df["gender"].value_counts().reset_index()
df
```

This returns:

```
    index   gender
0   male    3
1   female  2
```

Afterwards you can clean up by redefining the column names:

```
df.columns = ["gender", "counts"]
df
```

With the result:

```
    gender  counts
0   male    3
1   female  2
```